# SqlDataAdapter Fill method jumps execution

Tags: select, view, dataset, fill, sqldataadapter

i have a function which is called on form load
it should retrieve some data from a view and fill the dataset
but when it reaches the **da.Fill(ds);** line, all of the code below it (including itself) is awkwardly jumped
then form loads and my function becomes useless
below is the body of my function

```
SqlConnection conn = create_conn();
conn.Open();
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("View1", conn);
cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmd.Parameters.Add("keyfield", System.Data.SqlDbType.Char).Value = keyfieldval;
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
da.SelectCommand = cmd;
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
da.Fill(ds); // <--- THIS IS THE LINE
Form1.field1 = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["field1"].ToString();
Form1.field2 = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["field2"].ToString();
conn.Close();
```

Comment: did you try adding some exception handling? maybe your code is failing. use a try..catch and let us know what you catch, or turn on all exception handling to be caught by the debugger (ctrl+alt+e in VS08/10)

Comment: any error message/exception shown on screen? Please elaborate

Comment: there isnt any errors. i will use try catch now and let you know the result

Comment: this is the exception i got: "the request for procedure 'View1' failed because its a View object" :(

Comment: i understand the issue. i need to create a stored procedure that includes this code: select * from View1.. maybe i still get it wrong

Comment: this was a silly mistake. i tried to call a view, instead of a SP.  
i solved the issue by creating a SP that selects the data from my view. thanks for your suggestions